# Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I face the following problem in `firefox` and `google chrome` :

```
Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
```

I call the following javascript method `onclick` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var confirmSubmited = false;
        function SubmitWithLog(par_name, par_address, frm) {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/LogAction.ashx?par_name=" + par_name + "&par_address=" + par_address,
                type: "GET",
                timeout: 3000,
                async: true, // you can try and async:false - maybe is better for you
                data: action = 4, // here you send the log informations
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    jQuery(frm).submit();
                },
                error: function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    jQuery(frm).submit();
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

---

The link from firebug will render like this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="SubmitWithLog('%d8%b7%d9%84%d8%a8+%d8%a5%d9%84%d8%aa%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3+‌​%d9%84%d9%84%d9%85%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af+%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a8%d8%b4%d8%b1%d9%8a%d‌​8%a9','...../RequestList.aspx','#ctl43');return false;">GO </a>
```

---

according to the following link :

[Error: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.](http://wraithnath.blogspot.gr/2012/03/error-sysparametercountexception.html)

I set the `ScriptMode = "release"`

but i get another error

```
this._toFormattedString is not a function
```

This problem isn't exist in IE.

---

EDIT :

```
public class LogAction : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
    {


        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext con)
        {
            // log here what you wish
            string[] statistics = TrackUser();
            string a = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(con.Request.Params["Par_name"].ToString());
            string b = con.Request.Params["Par_address"].ToString();

            TraceActivity(a, b, statistics[0], statistics[1], statistics[2]);
            // end up with no content
            con.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            con.Response.Status = "204 No Content";
            con.Response.StatusCode = 204;
        }

    //-------------------------------------------
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure that this code have to do with the error, is it possible to give me the real url on web to see the full page ?

Comment: The web site still in developing phase :(

Comment: After i set `scriptmode =release`

Comment: `this._toFormattedString is not a function
http://localhost:6450/ScriptResource.axd?d=c09qoTA6dfckaZaU1EbZsSYMh0ulsf84hyhIwp8EsyQ8K9l2omRaAL6yG2On0FTR6TnG0SBKDf4adxeK_Ik0uyQijxKZ-faTK4m6iufvfEgqqeNkCiUxlQPqM7IMKhOVdltzawJyZ6OnIZ54_WXXUWTOCRI1&t=ffffffffb868b5f4
Line 5`
Get this error

Comment: Is the error coming from your Ajax request or from your form submission? What does LogAction.ashx do? Can you post the relevant server-side code?

Comment: the error comes from the `Ajax request` just when i click on the link .
The `LogAction.ashx` log the data about the site the user clicks on in the database.
`HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
a.Attributes["onclick"] = call SubmitWithLog method`

Comment: @just_name The error looks like a .NET error, and so is coming from LogAction.ashx. (`ScriptMode = "release"` only hides the error from the client; it doesn't fix anything.) What does the link render to in IE?

Comment: Please add the `$.noConflict();` right after you load the jQuery. As you see here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @JefferyTo :

`<a onclick="SubmitWithLog('%d8%b7%d9%84%d8%a8+%d8%a5%d9%84%d8%aa%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3+%d9%84%d9%84%d9%85%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af+%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a8%d8%b4%d8%b1%d9%8a%d8%a9','https://....../RequestList.aspx','#ctl43')" href="javascript:void(0)">`

Comment: @Aristos : i try to add this line after jquery loading but still the same error in firefox and chrome ..it works okay in `IE`..

Comment: I have the following only scripts at the end of the form :

Comment: `<script src="messageBox/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="messageBox/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/PortalJs/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/PortalJs/inettuts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/PortalJs/newwindow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: the first thing that is coming to mind is ,whatever you are doing at server side is taking very long time, so your request is timeout every time. this may be the cause the error.

Comment: then why it works with `IE` ??!!

Comment: wouldnt LogAction.ashx be LogAction.aspx?

Comment: @just_name How do you expect to get this resolved if you font respond?

Comment: sorry, I have a bad connection for long time

Comment: @AbstractChaos : no, there's just a handler `LogAction.ashx` ,no `LogAction.aspx` exists

Comment: If this is behaving differently between browsers, then my recommendation would be to change the parameter name `XMLHttpRequest` for the error function. That's a reserved javascript keyword, but since it is in the context of a parameter, it may be that different browsers handle it differently.

Comment: The same error : `this._toFormattedString is not a function http://localhost:6450/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=RadScript‌​Manager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Vers‌​ion%3d3.5.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3‌​a7263e9c6-5962-41bc-b839-88b704bfcf0d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+V‌​ersion%3d2011.2.712.35%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%‌​3aen-US%3a326e32e2-cd52-462c-ba2c-db5128e4371b%3a16e4e7cd%3addbfcb67%3af7645509%3‌​a24ee1bba%3a19620875%3a3f6e8f3f Line 6`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly worth wrapping your data: item in quotes

```
data: action = 4
```

becomes

```
data: "action = 4"
```

Answer (score 7):

Thats what happens when you call a public method of an ajax API with the incorrect number of parameters. For example, try `Boolean.parse("true", "what?")`. It only takes 1 parameter, you passed in 2 or your sending a null value.

also your submit link `...../RequestList.aspx` does not look like a proper address.
so make sure you are not passing null or wrong parameters.

Comment: @just_name Any comments? This should be the only reason your getting this error. If the answer did not lead to a solution please show your ashx function...

Comment: what did u mean by the public methods of `ajax  APi` ,i don't think i use some thing like this . i will show the ashx func

Comment: @just_name in your function change the Par_name Par_address to lower case.

Comment: The same error :

`this._toFormattedString is not a function
http://localhost:6450/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d3.5.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a7263e9c6-5962-41bc-b839-88b704bfcf0d%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2011.2.712.35%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a326e32e2-cd52-462c-ba2c-db5128e4371b%3a16e4e7cd%3addbfcb67%3af7645509%3a24ee1bba%3a19620875%3a3f6e8f3f
Line 6`

Answer (score 3):

setting debug="false" in de web.config seemed to remove the error

Comment: This works. You need to remove the debug="true" attribute from the 'configuration/system.web/compilation' node in the web.config. Or set it as false.