# Parameter count mismatch when creating datatable from remote ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im having this error :Parameter count mismatch ! I tried all the syntax with no luck to find a solution !

Please help ! im using ASP.net

My javascript code

```js
  (function (window, document, $, undefined) {
         //   $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
            $(function () {

                $('#datatable4').DataTable({
                    'Workflowing': true,
                    "responsive": true,
                   //   'serverSide': true,
                    ajax: {
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "WebPortal.asmx/GetTasksByUser?UserID=3&par=1",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        async: false,
                       data: JSON.stringify('{ UserID: "3"}'),
                        //data: function ( d ) {
                        //    d.UserID = '3'
                        //},
                        dataSrc: function (json) {
                           return JSON.parse(json.d)
                        }
                    "columns": [
                            ...My columns...  ]
                });
            });
        })(window, document, window.jQuery);
```

Am i missing something ?!

Comment: Possible duplicate? [sys-parametercountexception-parameter-count-mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032413/sys-parametercountexception-parameter-count-mismatch)

Comment: I tried the solution found on that link , it didn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 (function (window, document, $, undefined) {
             //   $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
                $(function () {

         mydata= {
                   UserID: "3"    
                 }
                    $('#datatable4').DataTable({
                        'Workflowing': true,
                        "responsive": true,
                       //   'serverSide': true,
                        $.ajax: {
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "WebPortal.asmx/GetTasksByUser?UserID=3&par=1",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false,
                           data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
                            //data: function ( d ) {
                            //    d.UserID = '3'
                            //},
                            dataSrc: function (json) {
                               return JSON.parse(json.d)
                            }
                        "columns": [
                                ...My columns...  ]
                    });
                });
            })(window, document, window.jQuery);
```