# Unable to pass value from C# to amcharts JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c#, amcharts, gauge

I created a chart with the help of amCharts that shows temperature from the examples on their site. The chart displayed correctly.

Now I am getting the temperature from a database with C# and I am trying to pass the value to the function where temperature was hard coded, so I get dynamic values. However, I just get the chart and the needle is still at 0 and does not show the temperature.

I have tried 3 ways so far:

1. I used a hidden field, assigned the value to hidden field in C# and called the JavaScript function showing the charts. It only shows chart. The needle does not change.
2. I used script manager and Web API, (I don't know Web API and just used code on the Internet), it is the same result however the function in c# keeps on being continuously called.
3. I put the entire amCharts code in a JavaScript function . I got values in c# and then used

   ```
   String script = "window.onload = function() { UpdateTemp('" + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()+ "'); };";
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UpdateTemp", script, true);
   ```

   which again shows same result, map is shown needle stays on 0.

This is my code for the 3rd approach:

**ASPX page, JavaScript function**

```
<script>
 function UpdateTemp(temp) {

     am4core.ready(function() {

            // Themes begin
            am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
            // Themes end

            // create chart
            var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.GaugeChart);
            chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect

            chart.innerRadius = -25;

            var axis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
            axis.min = 0;
            axis.max = 100;
            axis.strictMinMax = true;
            axis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet().getFor("background");
            axis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.3;

            var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();

            var range0 = axis.axisRanges.create();
            range0.value = 0;
            range0.endValue = 50;
            range0.axisFill.fillOpacity = 1;
            range0.axisFill.fill = colorSet.getIndex(0);
            range0.axisFill.zIndex = - 1;

            var range1 = axis.axisRanges.create();
            range1.value = 50;
            range1.endValue = 80;
            range1.axisFill.fillOpacity = 1;
            range1.axisFill.fill = colorSet.getIndex(2);
            range1.axisFill.zIndex = -1;

            var range2 = axis.axisRanges.create();
            range2.value = 80;
            range2.endValue = 100;
            range2.axisFill.fillOpacity = 1;
            range2.axisFill.fill = colorSet.getIndex(4);
            range2.axisFill.zIndex = -1;

            var hand = chart.hands.push(new am4charts.ClockHand());

            // using chart.setTimeout method as the timeout will be disposed together with a chart

            chart.setTimeout(randomValue, 2000);

            function randomValue(temp) {
                hand.showValue(temp, 1000, am4core.ease.cubicOut);
                chart.setTimeout(randomValue, 2000);
            }



        }); // end am4core.ready()

    };
</script>
```

**C# function to get temperature and call JavaScript function**

```
public void BindGrid(String charttype)
{

    string constring = "Data Source=********.DOMAIN.ORG01;Initial Catalog=Temperature;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Temperature,HighestPoint,LowestPoint FROM Temperature", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            temp1.Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            con.Close();
            String script = "window.onload = function() { UpdateTemp('" + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()+ "'); };";
             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UpdateTemp", script, true);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you add this as first instruction of your method "UpdateTemp" : "console.log(temp);" and you open the dev tools with your browser (ex: Chrome by taping F12), what do you see in the console ?

Comment: Hi Aliz, This is what i got in console

Comment: Where is it ? Did you forgot to update your post or paste the result in your comment ?

Comment: ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch                                                                                                                 at Function.Error$create [as create] (http://localhost:61681/ScriptResource.axd?d=D

Comment: Did you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032413/sys-parametercountexception-parameter-count-mismatch

Comment: I checked that link that you shared and ,but i didnt quite understand it.

Comment: I dont understand  data: "action = 4" ,as in my function i am just simply passing a parameter value to function    function randomValue(temp) {
                hand.showValue(temp, 1000, am4core.ease.cubicOut);
                chart.setTimeout(randomValue, 2000);
            }

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a screenshot of the rendering script ?
The error message says "Parameter count mismatch at Function.Error$create [as create] ", so if I try to interpret you try to call a function without the right number of parameters, if you could show what's outputed we would directly see the reason I think.

Comment: Basic question that come across my mind, are you sure your table "Temperature" is filled ? I see that you access the datarow directly without checking if the result may be null, that's dangerous.

Comment: I uploaded the image by editing the question.Yeah the value of temperature is filled when i fetch from database ,i checked the value in debug mode .I guess i should have check for null,but this is not a live project ,i was told by someone if you can show temperature in a gauge ,may be we can give work to you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality code should be revised but I managed to make it work.
I made 2 changes:

- 1 : I used the method "PageLoad" instead of "BindGrid" (do you really need this one ?)
- 2 : I filled the raw temperature value directly as a parameter (as it is a float on my side), you englobed your datarow value with simple quote, that's interpreted as string by javascript and the method "showValue" from "hand" seems to not tolerate it.

Code:
[image]

Result:

[image]

Some ideas to improve your code:

- Put your connection string in configuration file (never in code !)
- If you use the "using" do not matter calling the method "close" of your resource, it's automatically called by it. (behind the using it's in fact a try-catch-finally, the close is called anyway in the finally ;) )
- If possible separate the data access from the rendering page, create a separate class that manages it, it will improve readability and evolution of your code.
- If the variable "temp1" is not used, just remove it.
- When you get a data (no matter the source, could be a webservice or database or else), check **always** if it's null before access it and log it, it doesn't cost a lot and you avoid escalation of exceptions.
- We are in 2019, you could use [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/) to get directly object as result from your queries instead of a generic datarow. (check the website if interested they have a lot of interesting tutorials).

Kr,
Ali

Comment: I think this "check always if it's null before access it " is bad advice. You should know what possible responses there are for your data. If null is possible, handle it. If it should not be possible, let things fail fast. That way you see right away and can fix the issue.

Comment: "let things fail fast. ". I disagree, what happens if your website is live and you try to access a variable that should not be null and it is ? You display critical information like stack error to the end user ? I think the right way is to manage it locally, log it with meaningful information (exception data and maybe more context via a string) and throw a specific exception that will allow you to use appropriated action (display a popup, redirect, redirect logs, etc...) and most important above all, understand the issue as quickly as possible to be able to fix it fast

Comment: If you have a production website failure the correct course of action is to log the exception and display a 500 to the end user. You can make a pretty 500 page if you want. But you let the exception bubble. Trying to null check things "Just in case" hides so many issues and quickly makes your code nearly unmaintainable

Comment: It's an interesting subject, I found a topic about this question (there are surely more): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293328/null-values-handling-in-big-scale-applications
It seems that there is no univocal answer to this problematic, I would still advise to do it this way. (it saved me a lot of time so many times...)

Comment: Thank you,it is working now.I will make the changes regarding quality that you mentioned .